# Update panel from a server side thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, multithreading, updatepanel

I am trying to develop a chat using aspx. I already got it working with asmx + winform but now I have problems with asmx + aspx.

Basically what I want to do is call the WebMethod `CheckForMessages` every two seconds and, if there are messages, add them to a list box inside an update panel and do `UpdatePanel1.Update();`.

The problem is that apparently I can' t do this using a thread like I do in my winform.

```
void check() {
  while (true) {
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    string message = CheckForMessages();
    if (message != "") {
      ListBox1.Items.Add(message);
      UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
  }
}
```

I start the thread like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  timer = new Thread(new ThreadStart(check));
  timer.Start();
}
```

It doesn't throw an exception or anything, the program runs as intended. The web service is called, a string is returned if there is a message, the thread adds the message to the list and calls `UpdatePanel1.Update();`. Yet the panel is not updated.

What could the problem be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the server actively pushing changes to the client, try the opposite : make the client actively query the server, and update its state accordingly.

One way to do that is create a button to query the server manually. After you verify that it works, make the button hidden using css, and set a function to click the button in a regular interval. You can use javascript `setInterval` for this.

To click a button in javascript, you can do something like this :

```
setInterval(function(){ document.getElmtById(“<%= theButton.ClientID %>").click(); }, 2000);
```

The above code should click `theButton` every 2 seconds.

Comment: edit: i overestimated my javascript skills. could you provide a code sample to click a button every x seconds please ?

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.Net you can use timer control along with updatepanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="uxUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" EnableViewState="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="display:none;"><%=GetMessageLog()%></asp:Label> 
                <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="ListBox1" EnableViewState="true">

                </asp:ListBox>
            </div>           
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="uxTimer" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Timer runat="server" ID="uxTimer" Interval="2000">
    </asp:Timer>
```

And in Code-behind you to code like:

```
public string GetMessageLog()
{
    string message = CheckForMessages();
    if (message != "") {
      ListBox1.Items.Add(message);      
    return DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

This should work for you. But I will recommend you to use Javascript and JQuery to call Web-Service asynchronously with setTimeout function.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at SignalR.net. Jabbr.net is based on signalR and exactly what you need. https://github.com/davidfowl/JabbR

Answer (score 0):

yes Vishal... maybe less complex:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanelPromptB" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="labelPlayback" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate> 
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timerPromptB" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="timerPromptB" OnTick="timerPromptB_Tick" Enabled="false" Interval="4000" />

private void promptBottom(string text)
{
    labelPlayback.Text = text;
    updatePanelPromptB.Update();
    timerPromptB.Enabled = true;
}
protected void timerPromptB_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    labelPlayback.Text = "OK";
    timerPromptB.Enabled = false;
}
```